# Binding `this` through `call` not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, this

I'm trying to change an Express `app`'s `.set` function to be case-insensitive. Such that

```
app.set('PORT',80);
app.set('port'); // => undefined; trying to make it so that it returns 80
```

Internally it's just a function that alters the object's `settings` property. So I tried to make a wrapper

```
var set = app.set;
app.set = function(setting){
    setting = setting.toLowerCase();
    return set.call(app, arguments);
}
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't change the `app`'s settings property at all. As though it couldn't grab it through `this`.

What works is this:

```
app.set_ = app.set;
app.set = function(setting){
    setting = setting.toLowerCase();
    return app.set_(setting, arguments[1]);
}
```

So only if the `set_` is *attached* to the `app`, does it work.

But I thought `.call`ing the method and passing the `app` should do essentially the same, yet it doesn't. Why might that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `apply` not `call` for `arguments`, like:

```
set.apply(app, arguments)
```

Or use `call` with the one argument:

```
set.call(app, setting)
```

Or you can bind `app` permanently:

```
var set = app.set.bind(app)
```

Then call the function normally:

```
set(setting)
```